# Joomla social media landing page

Tags: twitter, joomla, social-media

I want to add social media icons (i.e. Twitter, Facebook, etc) to a Joomla-based site, so that after the social media message is sent by a user, they are redirected to a landing page.

Does anyone know if a plug-in or control that does this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use AddThis plugin to display social media icons on articles etc. Check out AddThis website.

Comment: Will the plugin redirect after the social submission? I will research this question.

Comment: It will open in new popup so no need for it to redirect.

Comment: I want to add a twitter button to a site so that the user can tweet a pre-formatted message and then see a coupon code. AddThis does not seem to do what I want. tweet4file will redirect to a file download after tweeting, but it is not free and having the user download a file with a coupon code in it is overly complex.